# How to refactor a class hierarchy of singletons where each class has a getInstance() method?

Tags: java, inheritance, refactoring, singleton

I have inherited a particular class hierarchy of singletons whose declarations are summarized below (there are more implementations -- I'm just showing the minimal set to demonstrate the problem).  It smells to high heaven to me, foremost because singletons are being inherited from,  as well as the way `instance` in the base class has its value overwritten in the static initializers of the subclasses.

If all the implementations were in the `foo.common` parent package I would consider just dropping the `instance` member and `getInstance()` methods from them, making the classes and their constructors package-local, and having some public factory class in `foo.common` create a single instance of each, hold onto that single instance of each internally (partitioned by whether it was an implementation of `IReadOnly` or `IReadWrite`) and provide a couple of public lookup methods where based on some enum it would return the asked-for implementation as the interface type.

But implementations can be outside of `foo.common` and `foo.common` isn't allowed to depend on such "more specific" packages, since `foo.common` is intended for stuff common to a bunch of apps. So something that simple can't be done.  What then?

First interface:

```
package foo.common.config;
public interface IReadOnly
{
    void load();
    String getVal(String key);
}
```

Second interface:

```
package foo.common.config;
public interface IReadWrite extends IReadOnly
{
    void save();
    void setVal(String key, String value);
}
```

First implementation:

```
package foo.common.config;
public class ReadOnlyImpl implements IReadOnly
{
    protected static IReadOnly instance;

    static {
        instance = new ReadOnlyImpl();
    }

    public static IReadOnly getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    protected ReadOnlyImpl() {}

    // implement methods in IReadOnly
}
```

Second implementation

```
package foo.common.config;
public class ReadWriteImpl extends ReadOnlyImpl implements IReadWrite
{
    static {
        instance = new ReadWriteImpl();
    }

    public static IReadWrite getInstance() {
        return (IReadWrite) instance;
    }

    protected ReadWriteImpl() {
        super();
    }

    // Implement methods in IReadWrite
}
```

Third implementation:

```
// While things in this package can depend
// on things in foo.common, nothing in 
// foo.common is allowed to depend on this package.
package foo.apps.someapp;
public class MoreSpecificReadWriteImpl extends ReadWriteImpl
{
    static {
        instance = new MoreSpecificReadWriteImpl();
    }

    public static IReadWrite getInstance() {
        return (IReadWrite) instance;
    }

    protected MoreSpecificReadWrite() {
        super();
    }

    // Override superclass methods to do something specific
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why/how you would like to refactor it? I really don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting package foo.apps.someapp aside, the design of the package  foo.common.config is wrong.

```
IReadOnly o1=ReadOnlyImpl.getInstance(); // ok, returns ReadOnlyImpl
...
ReadWrite o2=ReadWriteImpl.getInstance(); // ok, returns ReadWriteImpl 
...
IReadOnly o3=ReadOnlyImpl.getInstance(); // bad, returns ReadWriteImpl, the same as o2.
```

The reason is that all classes use the same static variable ReadOnlyImpl.instance. I would use separate variable in all classes, including MoreSpecificReadWriteImpl. If this would not fit, then think of using Spring container or similar framework.

Comment: Is there a typo your last line? It is same as first line.

Comment: No typo. It is not the same: o1 and o3.